# PHPプログラムを実行すると、どのファイルを見に行くのでしょうか？ バイナリファイル？

Tags: php, centos

**CentOSにyumでPHPをインストールしたと仮定**

・PHPプログラムを実行すると、どのファイルを見に行くのでしょうか？
・バイナリファイル(usr/bin/php？)？
・PHPの標準関数定義は、どのファイルで定義されているのでしょうか？
・コンパイルされた状態で1つのファイルとして存在している？

---

**追記**
・下記コマンド結果はどういう意味でしょうか？
・[このリンク先](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/163wherecomd.html)で掲載されているように、結果にaliasと表示されなければエイリアスではない？
・あるいはaliasと明示されなくてもエイリアスの可能性はある？

```
$ which -a php
```

> /opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin/php
>     /usr/bin/php

```
$ type -a php
```

> php is /opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin/php
>    php is /usr/bin/php

Comment: 実際の実行PATHが知りたいだけなら`which`の方でも良い気もします。`whereis`はコマンドの「実行PATH」「ソースファイル」「man」が返って来ますので適宜用途に応じて使い分けてどうぞ。

Comment: 内容難しかったです。「実際の実行PATH」とコマンドの「実行PATH」「ソースファイル」は何が異なるのでしょうか？ 私の環境では「実際の実行PATH」である「which」を試すと、ブラウザからPHPファイルを実行する際のパス「/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin/php」が表示されるのですが、コマンドの「実行PATH」「ソースファイル」は、なぜ「実際の実行PATH」と異なるのでしょうか？ コマンドでphpを実行した際は、「実際の実行PATH」を見に行かない？？？

Comment: コメントでかき続けるか迷いますが、少しだけ…コマンドの実行結果はそれぞれ環境によって異なりますが、`which`は"コマンドが存在するフルパス"になります。ですので実際実行されているファイルではなく実行ファイルへのエイリアス(ショートカット)の可能性もあります。一方`whereis`の1つ目は"実行コマンドのバイナリ"なので実行されるファイルの実体になります。

Comment: 大前提として、「コマンドのPHP実行結果」と「ブラウザからPHPファイルを実行した際の結果」が異なることはあり得るのでしょうか？

Comment: 同じ実行元パスであれば基本的に大きく変わることは無いかと思います。ただし、PHP内のスクリプトの内容次第ではないでしょうか？`php_sapi_name`の実行元判別が行われていればスクリプト内での処理の分岐も変わるでしょうし、コマンドラインを対象として組まれたスクリプトか、ApacheからのWEBを対象としているスクリプトかで変わるかと思います。(実行権限によってもアクセスできるモジュールが変わりますので、rootじゃないと実行できないスクリプトもあるかもしれないですね)、また同じ実行元と言ったのは実行するPHPがCGIかモジュールかで結果も変わりますので……

Answer (score 1):

**1), 2) への解答**
PHPの配置場所は**whereis**コマンドで、知ることができます。
私の環境だと

```
[vagrant@local ~]$ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib64/php /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini /usr/include/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

上記のようになっています。シンボリックリンクの可能性もありますが、/usr/bin/php, /usr/lib64/phpあたりにあると推測できます。

通常、/usr/binにパスが通っているので、phpの実行が可能となっています

**3), 4)**
標準関数はビルトイン、つまりバイナリの中に定義されています。
コード上の話であれば例えばですが、array系だと
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6053987bc27e8dede37f437193a5cad448f99bce/ext/standard/php_array.h
上記で定義されています。

Comment: 「/usr/bin/php」と「/usr/lib64/php」の違いは何でしょうか？　インストールを実行すると、「https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/6053987bc27e8dede37f437193a5cad448f99bce/ext/standard」内容がコンパイルされて、一つのファイルになるのでしょうか？ それが「/usr/bin/php」？ もしそうだとしたら「/usr/lib64/php」「/usr/include/php」「/usr/share/php」はどういう役割を果たすのでしょうか？